# What is the reason for making "Human Centipede 2" in black and white?

Tags: black-and-white, human-centipede-2

As per [Tom Six's claim](http://movieweb.com/exclusive-tom-six-reveals-more-on-the-human-centipede-ii-full-sequence/) for Human Centipede 2 to make it more graphic and disturbing, making the first film seem like "My Little Pony compared with part two." So why make it in black and white?

What is the reason for making it in B&W, is it for censorship issues or for achieving a cheap torture porn effect or is it for any other reason?

Comment: That movie is so bad they couldn't afford color.

Comment: It actually costs more to do the B&W these days. Most of the time they shoot in colour then decolourize it in post. The real question should be "What is the reason for making Human Centipede 2?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes filmmakers use black & white for showing the darker aspects of story.

For example in the 1998 film [American History X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_History_X), the parts of the movie where Edward Norton's character is a racist, are shown in Black & White, whereas the part of the movie where Edward Norton is no longer a racist and is seen repenting are shot in color. Take a look [here](http://www.studymode.com/essays/American-History-x-Analysis-Lighting-Color-85532.html).

So my point is that use of 'Black & White' in contemporary movies do deal with darker aspects of the story. Or let's say the use of 'Black & White' adds to the dark nature of a scene or a whole movie.

Adding to that, [Wikipedia entry of the movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Centipede_2_%28Full_Sequence%29) says

> "According to Six, he intentionally made Full Sequence very different
>   from First Sequence, due to two reasons. First, back when he was
>   writing the script of First Sequence, he knew people would want more
>   "blood and shit" than is shown, and second, the two parts reflect the
>   two different characters of their antagonists: the coloured First
>   Sequence, with a slow-moving camera, fit the story of Dr. Heiter,
>   while Martin Lomax's character required a "dark and dirty" film. **Six
>   shot Full Sequence in colour, but "was always thinking about black and
>   white" and realized while editing that it was "much scarier" in black
>   and white**"

So I guess, we have an idea now why it was made in Black & White.